# Catalan's conjecture: GCD of an algebraic expression

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to solve and understand Catalan's conjecture from [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2004-41-01/S0273-0979-03-00993-5/S0273-0979-03-00993-5.pdf) source.

As it is known, the conjecture states that the only solution in terms of consecutive numbers for$$x^p-y^q=1 \tag*{(1)}$$ is $(x,y,p,q)=(3,2,2,3)$.

Now, to solve $(1)$ in the general sense, the source (Page no. 4) does the following, 
$$x^p-1=y^q$$
$$(x-1)\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=y^q \tag*{(2)}$$

then the source goes on to consider $x^p$ as $((x-1)+1)^p$. Later they **conclude** that the GCD of the terms on the left hand side of $(2)$ is either $p$ or $1$.

How do they find the GCD here? And how can there be two GCDs (i.e., $p$ or $1$)?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{x^p - 1}{x - 1} = \sum_{k = 0}^{p - 1} x^k \equiv \sum_{k = 0}^{p - 1} 1^k = p \pmod{x - 1},
$$
so$$
\left( \frac{x^p - 1}{x - 1}, x - 1 \right) = (p, x - 1) = 1 \text{ or }p.
$$